# Get value of Firebase DB object as an object and change its keys?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to try and get a whole ref from a Firebase Realtime Database into an object, while changing some of its properties:

```
  const [events, setEvents] = React.useState([]);
  get(child(ref(getDatabase()), `events`)).then(snap => {
   setEvents([snap.val()])
  })
  // creating my object:
  events.map(ev => Object.keys(ev).map(item => ({
    title: ev[item].txt, // the original proparty from firebase is "txt", I wabt to get it as "title"
    image: ev[item].imgUrl,
    description: ev[item].description
  })))
```

It returned this:

[image]

With an extra "0" parent, but how can I get it this way:

[image]

This is the json:

```
  "events" : {
    "-MmZ5gjaPgQZj58NX3Us" : {
      "imgFile" : "77mhw.jpg",
      "imgUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zevik-4a379.appspot.com/o/77mhw.jpg?alt=media&token=e530272c-6e36-409d-ac68-0042ac17b971",
      "txt" : "sometxt"
    },
    "-MmZ5grbFb-6Bj5ew7Gv" : {
      "imgFile" : "bptmli.jpg",
      "imgUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zevik-4a379.appspot.com/o/bptmli.jpg?alt=media&token=5f99b26c-e184-43af-bc8b-95484b94f6a5",
      "txt" : "sometxt"
    },
    "-MmZ5gxeoHGTUDZ328RE" : {
      "imgFile" : "xj5fi.jpg",
      "imgUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zevik-4a379.appspot.com/o/xj5fi.jpg?alt=media&token=7058ea83-1abb-47f7-bcf3-eae2fb2af679",
      "txt" : "sometxt"
    }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON at `events` in the database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Just did :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the extra `0` level comes from the fact that you use `[]` in this call:

```
setEvents([snap.val()])
```

As far as I can tell that should be:

```
setEvents(snap.val())
```